# Add application to SQL CDC records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cdc

I want to implement CDC on a database but capture the application info from the process that made the change. Is there some way to get that information in the CDC data? I quite often get asked by clients of what changes were made to their data and who did that change. In the application information our software includes the user name of the person that was logged in at the time so between what can be  captured with CDC and that application info I can give them exactly what they want.

Comment: Change data capture (CDC) refers to the process of identifying and capturing changes made to data in a database and then delivering those changes in real-time to a downstream process or system.

Comment: The tool which is called CDC can return changes made, but it only works with the actual table data, so if it's not there, you can't get it, you can always log some extra info into the tables to be able to track it later

Comment: We do data change logging with table triggers. When an update occurs we log the app_name() associated with the change.